# Survey/questionnaire

Tags: questionnaire

TeX newbie here!

I am trying to make a questionnaire using [this code](https://github.com/annerosenisser/latex-surveys/blob/master/latex-surveys.tex) but I want to make bigger boxes, suitable for writing numbers or data not just to cross, such as the image and an option to increase the number of cells if possible.
Thanks in advance for any help =)

[image: Bigger boxes not to cross but to fill with data]

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Links to external files are discouraged because your question might become meaningless if/when the link disappears (next week, or next year, or... ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fbox` with `phantom` to show a box easily with minimum code. It's flexible because you can easily fix the size that depends on the text inside (`text` in this example).

```
\fbox{\phantom{text}}    
\fbox{\phantom{long text}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Further elaboration on the [answer of mmr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622630/):

You can use a framed box (`\fbox`) with a phantom number in it. The `\phantom` command reserves the space that its argument would take, but doesn't actually print the argument. So, for example `\fbox{\Large\phantom{10}}` creates a box that is the size of the number 10 in the `\Large` font size.

You can put this box at the end of a line using `\hfill`, which fills the space between the existing contents of a line before the fill command and the contents after it, for example:

```
\item some item\hfill\fbox{\Large\phantom{10}}
```

Putting the boxes at the right of the page does not always look good, especially when the text of the list items is short. To improve this you can put a `minipage` environment around the list with a width that is smaller than the full page, for example `0.6\textwidth`. This causes `\hfill` to fill up to 60% of the line width instead of the full page.

To put the box items in an alphabetically numbered list as in the screenshot from the question you can use `\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*]`. The `label=` syntax requires the `enumitem` package but this is already loaded by the survey template. For consistency with the rest of the survey template you can use additional spacing settings for vertical item distance (`itemsep`) and left margin (`leftmargin`).

A full list of this type is for example as follows:

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*,itemsep=0ex,leftmargin=2.8em]
\item Diabetes educator\hfill\fbox{\Large\phantom{10}}
\item Dietician\hfill\fbox{\Large\phantom{10}}
\item Podiatrist\hfill\fbox{\Large\phantom{10}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
```

To make the definitions easier to use you can define a new command for the list items (called `\bignumber` in the code below) and a new environment for the list as a whole (called `bignumlist`). In the code below the list environment has an argument that determines the width of the minipage.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,BCOR10mm,oneside,headsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wasysym}% provides \ocircle and \Box
\usepackage{enumitem}% easy control of topsep and leftmargin for lists
\usepackage{color}% used for background color
\usepackage{forloop}% used for \Qrating and \Qlines
\usepackage{ifthen}% used for \Qitem and \QItem
\usepackage{typearea}
\areaset{17cm}{26cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1cm}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{Example questionnaire created with \LaTeX}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\cfoot{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Beginning of questionnaire command definitions %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%
%% 2010, 2012 by Sven Hartenstein
%% mail@svenhartenstein.de
%% http://www.svenhartenstein.de

%% \Qq = Questionaire question. Oh, this is just too simple. It helps
%% making it easy to globally change the appearance of questions.
\newcommand{\Qq}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

%% \QO = Circle or box to be ticked. Used both by direct call and by
%% \Qrating and \Qlist.
\newcommand{\QO}{$\Box$}% or: $\ocircle$

%% \Qrating = Automatically create a rating scale with NUM steps, like
%% this: 0--0--0--0--0.
\newcounter{qr}
\newcommand{\Qrating}[1]{\QO\forloop{qr}{1}{\value{qr} < #1}{---\QO}}

%% \Qline = Again, this is very simple. It helps setting the line
%% thickness globally. Used both by direct call and by \Qlines.
\newcommand{\Qline}[1]{\noindent\rule{#1}{0.6pt}}

%% \Qlines = Insert NUM lines with width=\linewith. You can change the
%% \vskip value to adjust the spacing.
\newcounter{ql}
\newcommand{\Qlines}[1]{\forloop{ql}{0}{\value{ql}<#1}{\vskip0em\Qline{\linewidth}}}

%% \Qlist = This is an environment very similar to itemize but with
%% \QO in front of each list item. Useful for classical multiple
%% choice. Change leftmargin and topsep accourding to your taste.
\newenvironment{Qlist}{%
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\QO}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.5em,topsep=-.5em]
}{%
\end{itemize}
}

%% \Qtab = A "tabulator simulation". The first argument is the
%% distance from the left margin. The second argument is content which
%% is indented within the current row.
\newlength{\qt}
\newcommand{\Qtab}[2]{
\setlength{\qt}{\linewidth}
\addtolength{\qt}{-#1}
\hfill\parbox[t]{\qt}{\raggedright #2}
}

%% \Qitem = Item with automatic numbering. The first optional argument
%% can be used to create sub-items like 2a, 2b, 2c, ... The item
%% number is increased if the first argument is omitted or equals 'a'.
%% You will have to adjust this if you prefer a different numbering
%% scheme. Adjust topsep and leftmargin as needed.
\newcounter{itemnummer}
\newcommand{\Qitem}[2][]{% #1 optional, #2 notwendig
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\stepcounter{itemnummer}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{\stepcounter{itemnummer}}{}
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=2pt,leftmargin=2.8em]
\item[\textbf{\arabic{itemnummer}#1.}] #2
\end{enumerate}
}

%% \QItem = Like \Qitem but with alternating background color. This
%% might be error prone as I hard-coded some lengths (-5.25pt and
%% -3pt)! I do not yet understand why I need them.
\definecolor{bgodd}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{bgeven}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\newcounter{itemoddeven}
\newlength{\gb}
\newcommand{\QItem}[2][]{% #1 optional, #2 notwendig
\setlength{\gb}{\linewidth}
\addtolength{\gb}{-5.25pt}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\value{itemoddeven}}{0}}{%
\noindent\colorbox{bgeven}{\hskip-3pt\begin{minipage}{\gb}\Qitem[#1]{#2}\end{minipage}}%
\stepcounter{itemoddeven}%
}{%
\noindent\colorbox{bgodd}{\hskip-3pt\begin{minipage}{\gb}\Qitem[#1]{#2}\end{minipage}}%
\setcounter{itemoddeven}{0}%
}
}
%%% command for creating a box for a hand-written number
\newcommand{\bignumber}[1]{%
\item #1\hfill\fbox{\Large\phantom{10}}%
}
%%% environment for filling in numbers
\newenvironment{bignumlist}[1]{%
\begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*,itemsep=0ex,leftmargin=2.8em]
}
{%
\end{enumerate}%
\end{minipage}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% End of questionnaire command definitions %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\section*{About you}

\Qitem{ \Qq{How many times have you visited these health professionals?}

\begin{bignumlist}{0.6}
\bignumber{Diabetes educator}
\bignumber{Dietician}
\bignumber{Podiatrist}
\end{bignumlist}
}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]